# A-Frame 3D Model and Texture Loading Issues

Tags: textures, aframe, 3d-model

I'm new to A-Frame and have been able to load a few gltf models that have loaded with the proper textures. The last gltf model I was able to load just comes in as a grey model and the texture does not load.

Now, whenever I try to add a new a-entity or geometric primitive, nothing happens and the elements do not come up in the scene inspector and they do not appear in the scene either.

I'm using A-Frame 0.9, am running a local server, and am using Google Chrome to view the page. I'm confused as to why no elements I add will show up now when I am adding them no differently than I was before.

I tried adding the new elements both as a-entities and also just as the model or geometric primitive.

For the textures, I tried to go into the scene inspector and make sure that the texture had loaded for that model, and it had.

Here is my body section

```
    <body>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="sky" src="sky.jpg">
    <img id="courtTexture" src="NBACourt.jpg">
    <img id="scoreboardTexture" src="scoreboardTextureMap.png">
    <!-- <a-asset-itm id="mockCourtModel-obj" src="mockCourtforWebVR.obj"></a-asset-itm>
    <a-asset-itm id="mockCourtModel-mtl" src="mockCourtforWebVR.mtl"></a-asset-itm> -->
    <a-asset-item id="mockCourtglbmodel" src="mockCourt.glb">
    <a-asset-item id="scoreboardglbmodel" src="scoreboard.glb">
    <!-- <a-asset-item id="bleacher1glbmodel" src="bleacher.glb"> -->
    <a-asset-item id="basketball" src="basketballTexture.jpg">
  </a-assets>

  <a-entity id="sky" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 3000" material="shader: flat; src: #sky; side: back"></a-entity>

  <a-sphere position="0 0 0" radius=".05962739943" color="#CF5300"></a-sphere>

  <!-- Lighting -->
  <a-entity light="type: ambient; color: #BBB"></a-entity>
  <a-entity light="type: directional; color: #FFF; intensity: 1.5" position="-0.5 1 1"></a-entity>

  <a-entity gltf-model="#mockCourtglbmodel" material="src: #courtTexture" scale=".01 .01 .01"></a-entity>
  <a-entity gltf-model="#scoreboardglbmodel" material="src: #scoreboardTexture" scale=".01 .01 .01" position="0 4.091 0"><a-entity>
    <!-- Having a weird issue where the texture mapping isn't mapping or adding to the scoreboard correctly. -->

    <!-- This bleacher model will not load -->
  <!-- <a-entity gltf-model="bleacher1glbmodel" material="color: #868b94" scale=".01 .01 .01"></a-entity> -->

  <a-entity id="ball" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: .05962739943" material="shader: flat; src: #basketball"></a-entity>
```

I keep getting the "Type Error: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided" and also warnings about my textures being non powers of 2. I have another texture that loads in the scene that is not a power of 2 and it still loads fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with materials for a gltf, you must work with them on the THREEjs level. Gltf-model is a container that holds many objects, including groups, models, camera, etc. It's scene graph in itself, so you can't simply assign a material to it like you would with an aframe element `a-entity`.

Here is what you need to do to adjust the materials on objects inside a gltf

1. create a custom component, and add its name to the gltf-model entity.
2. inside the component code, add an event listener, for "model-loaded", so your variable references to the gltf will not return undefined.
3. inside the listener function, get the object3D('mesh'), which returns the group of all the objects in the gltf.
4. traverse through the mesh, and find (by name) the model you are looking for, and assign a variable to that model. Then use that variable to access the material, and modify it with code.
   Check out this glitch that shows how to do all of this.

https://glitch.com/~gltf-texturedemo

Comment: Do you think this is the reason no other components I add will load either? Even a simple sphere will not show up

Comment: If you have a gltf that is throwing an error, that will break the program and prevent other models from loading. Remove the bad gltf element and see if the programs works again. If so, you know that gltf has the problem. It's always best to reduce your scene to the bare minimum when working out a problem. Start a new project, and just load the bad gltf. Go back to the source of the gltf (your 3d app), and try to discover if you have corrupt geometry or textures. Once you have clean gltf that load properly, then you can use the tools I outlined above to modify your materials within aframe.

Comment: Thank you! Within those tools, is there a way to rotate textures and such? I had UVs  created for the model in Maya, but once I have the model in a-frame, the texture does not follow those UVs

Comment: yes. the uvs imported into gltf will come through. Insure that they are map channel 0 in maya. You can adjust the uvs in aframe, again by accessing the THREEjs material inside the traverse function. To adjust UVs on a texture expose the texture like this `node.material.texture.rotation = x` See the THREEjs docs for list of property names.     https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture